# Create XSD for defined XML and Table

Tags: sql-server, xml, xsd, schema, xmltable

I would like to build an import interface for a sql-server database which works with XML files. Now I got stuck in creating a XSD File to ensure a correct input-xml.

Let's say I  have a table like this:

```
table:    accounts
colummns: account_id INT NOT NULL
          name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
          type CHAR(1) NOT NULL
          desc VARCHAR(100)
```

and the xml file should look like this:

```
<accounts>
    <account>
        <account_id>1</account_id>
        <name>account A</name>
        <type>B</type>
    </account>
    <account>
        <account_id>2</account_id>
        <name>account B</name>
        <type>D</type>
        <desc>some text here</desc>
    </account>
</accounts>
```

It's the first time I am designing something like this and I have no experience with xsd file ...
I tried several things like `SELECT .. FOR XML AUTO, XMLSCHEMA` and XSD.exe but nothing gave me what I wanted.

I want to map the types of the SQL-Server Table in XSD - such like nullable/not nullable and length of strings. Even a range of valid values should be declared (e.g. `type` can only be A,B,C or D).

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT * FROM [accounts] FOR XML PATH('account'), ROOT('accounts')
```

Comment: This shows the XML Data from the table --> but what i need is the XSD, not the xml.

Comment: You can combine XSD schema generated by SELECT TOP(1) * FROM [Accounts] FOR XML AUTO, XMLSCHEMA ('MyURI') with xml structured by your needs in select above.

Comment: You could generate XSD from XML here - http://xmlgrid.net/xml2xsd.html and then describe type and use by using the information provided in MS SQL generated XSD. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution with XSD.exe - Just created an XSD an then adopted it, but it's hard work if you're totally new to this topic ;-)